# How to cast a reflect.Value by its type when created by reflect.New

Tags: go, reflection

I'm actually trying some black magic using reflection in golang :P

I got something like this :

```
  var _int int
  var _int32 int32
  var _int64 int64
  var _string string

    var nilablesIndex map[int]reflect.Value
    var nilables = map[string]reflect.Type {
           "int32":     reflect.TypeOf(_int32)},
           "int64":     reflect.TypeOf(_int64)},
           "int":       reflect.TypeOf(_int)},
           "string":    reflect.TypeOf(_string)},
        }
nilablesIndex[len(m) - 1] = reflect.New(nilables[field.Type.String()][1])
```

To summarize, I have at this moment a reflect.Value created by `reflect.New(nilables[field.Type.String()][1])`

That I want is to cast this variable by its original type.

Example : If `nilablesIndex[0]` is a `reflect.Type int32`, I want to cast it to type `int32`.

Is it possible ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it dynamic, because you are actually converting to a *concrete* type (what would be the type of the result if it would be dynamic? `interface{}`? you'd be back at the start).

You may use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) and a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

For example:

```
var i int32 = 3

v := reflect.ValueOf(i)

x := v.Interface().(int32)
fmt.Printf("%T %v", x, x)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MJxmdihKg1)):

```
int32 3
```

Comment: So finally that confirms my thoughts, that's can't be dynamic ... Thank you icza :-)

Comment: @Antony360 How could it be dynamic? What would be the type of the result? `interface{}`? Then you're back at the beginning.

Comment: I work on a bdd builder (dbr).
I have to use special variables type to store values from the bdd.
I call them "nillables type". For example nillable type is something like `dbr.NullInt64`, it's a structure containing an `int64` variable and a `bool` variable named `Valid` (will be `true` if the `int64` variable's not `NULL`). (cf: https://github.com/gocraft/dbr/blob/master/types.go)

Comment: To give you an example, if I want to get an `int` value in the bdd I got to declare a variable with the `dbr.NullInt64` type (cause there is not `dbr.NullInt`).
What I actually do is to create dynamicly a `dbr.NullInt64` variable when there is an `int` variable then I store the `int` value into this `dbr.NullInt64` and my desire is to finally cast it into its original type.